# Explanation of prime gap result

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In a [video](https://youtu.be/pp06oGD4m00?t=12m16s) here the author (t. tao) says that following is easy consequence of: prime number theorem (PNT) and pigeonhole principle.
He talks about this result:

```
P[n+1]-P[n]>=log P[n]
```

Can someone break it down, why this is the case?
How come above follows from PNT and pigeonhole principle?

Comment: There must be more to it. As written, it's wrong, we have $p_{n+1} - p_n \leqslant 246$ infinitely often. Is it about the average of the prime gaps?

Comment: I guess the claim that there exists infinitely many $n$ such that this is true...

Comment: @DanielFischer please feel free to check the link very soon in matter of seconds the equation I wrote should be on the board. (13:21)

Comment: @johna In fact Twin prime conjecture means that $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=2$ for infinitely many $n$ so Daniel is right, this can't be true for all $n$.

Comment: There are two statements (12:58 - 13:44): "among the primes $\leq x$, there is a prime gap $p_{n+1}-p_n \geq (1+o(1))\ln x$", equiv. to "the prime gap $p_{n+1}-p_n \geq (1+o(1))\ln x$ infinitely often".  Your question would be vastly better with this information explicit in it.  (Inequalities by \$p_{n+1}-p_n \geq (1+o(1))\ln x\$.)

Comment: @EricTowers Can you please edit it? my question

Comment: There is absolutely no need to call people stupid. Please edit that out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The least fancy way to express this:  Not all the prime gaps can be shorter than average (otherwise the average would be smaller).  The PNT tells you the average gap size and that the gaps are not all the same from some point on (the average gap size slowly increases).  The pigeonhole principle here uses two bins: $p_{n+1}-p_n \geq \ln p_n$ and $p_{n+1}-p_n < \ln p_n$.  If, for some $N$, all the $n>N$ have gap sizes in the second bin,  then the average gap size is smaller than the PNT says it is.${}^1$  Consequently, you never run out of gap sizes in the first bin; that is, there are infinitely many prime gaps $p_{n+1}-p_n \geq \ln p_n$.

[WimC's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2613806/123905) expresses this for *any* sequence $(s_1, s_2, \dots)$ having average gap size $\alpha \ln s_n$ for some constant $\alpha \in (0,1)$.  He's showing that this application of the pigeonhole principal applies to any sequence with the density given by the PNT, not just to the primes.  So the argument Dr. Tao is referencing doesn't depend on (extra) features of the primes, just on the average gap size given by the ("easy") PNT.  WinC is also showing that the "$1+o(1)$" isn't essential either -- if you have any constant there, no matter how close to zero, you never run out of gaps bigger than the average.

${}^1$: This depends on the fact that there are infinitely many primes.  If we split the sequence of gaps into a finite initial segment and the infinite sequence after that, the average gap size is the average of the infinite part -- the contribution from the finite segment is overwhelmed by the contribution from the infinite part.  As simple model of this:  for the sequence $(1, 0, 0, 0, \dots, 0, \dots)$, find the average of the first $k$ terms.  It's $1/k$.  As you let $k$ go to $\infty$, the average shrinks to zero.  That is, the contribution from the finite initial segment is gradually overwhelmed by the average of infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: "Not all the prime gaps can be shorter than average (otherwise the average would be smaller). "- I already lost you here. Ok maybe I should not have asked and watched the video in the first place as maybe my math background is not sufficient to understand the answer to the question; or you might need to break it down too much, which I don't ask for as it wouldn't be fair, and I can live without explanation given I watched the "wrong video" assuming my math level. ps I thought pnt was about p(n+1)-p(n) < n/ln n.

Comment: The [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) says $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ \pi(x)\ }{\frac{x}{\ln x}}=1$, that is, the ratio of the number of primes less than or equal to $x$ gets ever closer to $x/\ln(x)$ as $x$ gets bigger and bigger.  (There are strengthenings which are sometimes also called PNTs, for example, $\pi(x)=\mathrm{Li}(x)+O\left(x\mathrm{e}^{-a\sqrt{\ln x}}\right)$.) How this leads to gap estimates is explained somewhat [here](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html).

Comment: However, the idea that "not everything can be below average" is easy.  Consider a basketball team.  Each member has some height, generically not all the same, and there is some average of those heights.  Not all the members can be shorter than the average, otherwise the average would have been lower.  (If every member has the same height, then this doesn't quite work and we should be more precise in our statements.  This can't happen for primes, because the gaps slowly increase as we go to larger and larger numbers.  Also, we *were* careful, using $\geq$ in the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's first forget about primes. Instead let $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $m \geq 1$ and $2\leq p_1<p_2<\ldots$ be *any* increasing sequence such that $p_{k+1}-p_k < \alpha \log(p_k)$ for all $k\geq m$. Then for any $n >m$ $$ p_n-p_m = \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(p_{k+1}-p_k) < \alpha \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} \log(p_k) < \alpha (n-m) \log(p_n)$$ or $$\frac{p_n}{\log(p_n)} < \alpha(n-m) + \frac{p_m}{\log(p_n)}.$$ By the PNT this precludes the sequence of prime numbers for any choice of $\alpha$ and $m$. In other words, for the sequence of prime numbers and any $\alpha\in (0,1)$, $m\geq 1$ there is an index $n>m$ such that $p_{n+1}-p_n \geq \alpha \log(p_n)$.

Comment: actually I think I followed all your derivations except your last sentence.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why PNT precludes this, I am new to PNT can't get this.