# How does the pigeonhole Principle imply that $\exists$ $p_{n+1} - p_n \geq \log x$ such that $p_n,p_{n+1} \leq x$?

Tags: number-theory

This is the video [video](https://youtu.be/pp06oGD4m00?t=778) where the professor talks about prime gaps. I do not know much advanced mathematics. However, I do know about the Pigeonhole Principle and fail to see how it applies in this scenario.

Looking at the result, I think that the different prime gaps of primes less than $x$ represent the "holes" and the numbers from $1$ to $\log x$ represent the "pigeons".

The question was [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2613858/538409) previously and the answer said "The pigeonhole principle here uses two bins: $p_{n+1}-p_n \geq \ln p_n$ and $p_{n+1}-p_n < \ln p_n$.  If, for some $N$, all the $n>N$ have gap sizes in the second bin,  then the average gap size is smaller than the PNT says it is".

What does the PNT say about the average gap size for primes less than $x$?